# Migrating from Magento 2.0x to 2.1 using Data Migration Tool 2?

Tags: magento2

I wanted to setup a fresh Magento 2.1 install on our test / dev server. Can I use the data migration tool 2 to migrate customer / orders / etc ..?

Thanks

Comment: Thats not what the data migration tool is for .. Why not just use composer in the current version to upgrade it to 2.1?

Comment: Data Migration tool is used to migrate data from old site to new site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can migrate first you need to setup Magento2.0 database in new server and  map with new Magento2.1. You may face few issue but you can resolve it easily 
now you don't need any migration tool.